# Is it possible to Differentiate without respect to a variable

Tags: derivatives

I came upon a question where the solution shows that $\alpha$d$\theta$ = ($\theta$ + 1)d($\theta$ +1) becomes ad$\theta$ = ($\theta$ + 1)d$\theta$. I am a little lost as to how this occurs. Was the part of d($\theta$ + 1) differentiated without respect to any variable so that what you are left with is d$\theta$ or was there some other manipulation that occured?

Comment: $\frac d{dx}f(x)=f'(x)\implies df(x)=f'(x)dx$, just as a guide to how people write these things.

Comment: The point is that $\frac d{d\theta}(\theta+1) = 1$, so $d(\theta+1) = 1\,d\theta$.

Comment: [Here's a primer](https://bridge.math.oregonstate.edu/papers/CMJdifferentials.pdf) on differentials, i.e. differentiation without respect to a specific variable.